# Database constraints not created in arquillian tests with remote JBoss AS 7.2.0

Tags: java, jboss, jboss-arquillian

I have a JavaEE project which was not changed for several months. Tests were performed with this configuration:

```
<dependencies>
  <dependency>
     <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.junit</groupId>
     <artifactId>arquillian-junit-container</artifactId>
     <scope>test</scope>
     <version>1.0.0.CR7</version>
  </dependency>
</dependencies>

<profile>
     <id>arq-jbossas-remote</id>
     <activation><activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault></activation>
     <dependencies>
        <dependency>
           <groupId>org.jboss.as</groupId>
           <artifactId>jboss-as-arquillian-container-remote</artifactId>
           <version>7.1.0.Final</version>
           <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
     </dependencies>
  </profile>
```

This is running fine with `JBoss AS 7.1.1.Final "Brontes"`. 
No I want to update to a recent version of JBoss AS. When switching to `JBoss EAP 6.1.0.GA (AS 7.2.0.Final-redhat-8)` (and also newer versions) and changing the profile-version to *7.2.0.Final*  I realize that several tests (checking that duplicate type-code combinations are note allowed) were failing because of a constraint *not* created in the MySQL database.

```
@Entity
@Table(uniqueConstraints = @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = {"type","code"}))
```

I also tried the recent version *1.1.8.Final* of `arquillian-junit-container` with the same effect.

**Update1** I'm creating a @Deployment like this, the `persistence.xml` is a usual hibernate persistence-unit. Before each test cycle the test-database is dropped and created, the tables are created using `hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=create`.

```
@Deployment public static Archive<?> createTestArchive()
{
  WebArchive wa = ShrinkWrap.create(WebArchive.class, "test.war");
  ...
  wa.addAsResource("test/persistence.xml", "META-INF/persistence.xml");
}
```

**Update2** Here is the persistence.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.0"
  xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd"> 
<persistence-unit name="test">
  <jta-data-source>java:jboss/datasources/DsTest</jta-data-source>
  <properties>
     <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="false"/>
     <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create"/>
     <property name="hibernate.max_fetch_depth" value="0" />
     <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect"/>
  </properties>
</persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Comment: I'm confused - what does arquillian have to do with database constraints? What do you use to generate your ddl and deploy it to your database for the test run?

Comment: You are right, arquillian does not create the database constraints, arquillian is only packaging the web archive and executing the tests (see update 1).

Comment: Do you want to add your `persistence.xml` to the question?

Comment: Of course, see update 2!